# Interpreting glmer output

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme

I find myself buried deep into a generalised linear mixed effect model, slightly out of my depth, and need help interpreting what its saying and diagnosing the model assumptions.

The model:

```
mm_glmm_3 <- glmer(cbind(MissedMeds_N, TotalAdministrations) ~ month_id + factor(CareHomeSize) + factor(Ratings) + (1|FacilityKey), 
                   family = "binomial", data = facs_3mth, na.action = "na.omit", nAGQ = 0)
```

My goal is to evidence a reduction in the `MissedMeds_N`:`TotalAdministrations` ratio over time (`month_id`) and communicate this to our marketing guys.

- `CareHomeSize` is the size of the care home: 1 for small, 2 for medium, and 3 for large.
- `Ratings` is the quality of care being given at the care home as rated by regulatory bodies: 1 for inadequate, 2 for requiring improvement, 3 for good, and 4 for outstanding (there are no 1 or 2's in this data).
- `FacilityKey` is the unique identifier for each care home facility. I've got repeated measures so I'm adding a random intercept effect for care home facility.

The summary:

```
> summary(mm_glmm_3) # negative month_id, significant
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Adaptive Gauss-Hermite Quadrature, nAGQ = 0) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: cbind(MissedMeds_N, TotalAdministrations) ~ month_id + factor(CareHomeSize) +      factor(Ratings) + (1 | FacilityKey)
   Data: facs_3mth

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 21058.9  21095.1 -10522.5  21044.9     1288 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-16.4066  -1.0167  -0.0825   0.8157  29.3459 

Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 FacilityKey (Intercept) 2.372    1.54    
Number of obs: 1295, groups:  FacilityKey, 171

Fixed effects:
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           -5.0890719  0.4455409 -11.422   <2e-16 ***
month_id              -0.0062290  0.0006099 -10.213   <2e-16 ***
factor(CareHomeSize)2  0.2843053  0.3637577   0.782    0.434    
factor(CareHomeSize)3  0.4440538  0.3985768   1.114    0.265    
factor(Ratings)3       0.4166752  0.3246113   1.284    0.199    
factor(Ratings)4       0.1053528  0.4212772   0.250    0.803    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) mnth_d f(CHS)2 f(CHS)3 fc(R)3
month_id    -0.011                              
fctr(CrHS)2 -0.712  0.000                       
fctr(CrHS)3 -0.749  0.000  0.754                
fctr(Rtng)3 -0.689  0.000  0.106   0.243        
fctr(Rtng)4 -0.429  0.001 -0.012   0.045   0.583
```

What can I say from this output? Can I use something like:

"For every increase in month_id, the missed med to total administration ratio reduces significantly by 0.006 after controlling for size, rating and random variation between care facilities (and that this is significant (p <0.05))."

Would that be accurate? The fact that month_id is negative is a good news story, because it shows that missed medications are reducing when clients are using our system, regardless of size or rating.

And how do I read the coefficients for size and ratings? Is `CareHomeSize2` a comparison against the reference size, i.e. `CareHomeSize1`, and does that mean missed medications increase over time for sizes 2 and 3?

Finally, is DHARMa package the way to go to verify these models? Or is there anything else I should look at?